# Should the [metaphor] questions on Stack Overflow all be closed?

Tags: discussion, tags

In my ever widening quest through the tags on Stack Overflow, I've come to [metaphor](/questions/tagged/metaphor).  Looking through the list of questions:

- [What Are Your Go To Software Metaphors When Working With Non-Technical Management?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968)
- [Is there a dictionary about common programming vocabulary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708812)
- [What has been your most helpful Software Design/OOP Metaphor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274066)
- [Which metaphor would you use to describe programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620485)
- [Unmaintainable code behind to the non-technical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297156)
- [Are there any good metaphors for explaining project complexity to a non-programmer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278026)
- [Rails and MVC metaphors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885777)
- [What is the next great UI metaphor that will replace the Desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336609)
- [What do you think of "Programming is Gardening, not Engineering"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328141)

---

The remaining four question may add value to Stack Overflow and perhaps should be considered separately.

- [Is there a dictionary about common programming vocabulary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708812)
- [What is the best way to document a system metaphor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746896)
- [Are there any structured methodologies for defining metaphors to simplify complexity in programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237858)
- [MVC (model-view-controller) - can it be explained in simple terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626803)

**Should all of the above 13 questions be closed as off-topic, etc**?  If they are then could we also **consider burninating the tag [metaphor](/questions/tagged/metaphor)?**?

However, several of these questions are fairly old.  Hence, I'm unsure if these questions should be closed & deleted.  Perhaps protected?  Perhaps locked.